# CodedUI test cannot connect to TFS online after password reset

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to connect CodedUI tests to tfs.

[TestMethod, Priority(1), DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", "https://[company].visualstudio.com;[projectname]", "123", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

I am getting the following error:

Message: The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.
Error details: Type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException' in Assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.17.2.31801, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

This worked just fine before I reset my active directory password.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue after updating my VSTS password.  I did several things at the same time, so I'm not exactly sure if one particular action or a combination of things  resolved the issue.

- First thing I did was log out of all MSDN accounts in all browsers (not sure this would matter)
- Next, I opened VS 2015 and VS 2017 and signed out of all accounts
- And finally, I removed any VSTS and TFS credentials in the Credential Manager

That seems to have resolved the issue I was experiencing.  Hope that helps!